# How do I delete all my activity history with Microsoft?

Tags: privacy, microsoft-account

I just found out there was still activity being recorded at https://account.microsoft.com/privacy/activity-history despite me answering 'don't use my data' to all the questions in the last large Windows update.

I *think* I turned that off now (via Windows privacy settings), but how do I batch-delete all the entries left there? There are hundreds, so deleting them one by one would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna clear all the **HISTORY** then-

[image: 1st Step]

[image: 2nd step]

Answer (score 0):

Batch-deletions are only supported per activity type, so I had to select each in the `Filter by data type`-list to the left first (excluding `All data types`). The activity can then be deleted with the `Clear activity` button to the right.

Comment: I admit I completely failed to notice the instructions in that block of text near the top of the page. I think the marketing-speak in the first sentence switched off my brain or something.

Comment: (This answer is outdated now, since the website changed at some point.)